# Nesbot Carbon - Difference in whole months? (Laravel)

Tags: laravel-5, php-carbon

I'm trying to use Carbon to return the difference in months, but I want it to be calendar months, not calculated months.

```
$diff = Carbon::parse('2019-06-30')->diffInMonths(Carbon::parse('2019-07-01'), false);
dd($diff); //returns 0
```

Does anybody know if there's a simple way to do this in Carbon?

The reason is to apply a discount to a base rate if a certain number of months has passed since the item went on sale, and calculate the discount based on how many calendar months have gone by.

Answer (score 4):

In case this helps anybody else, Carbon has rounding features (https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-modifiers), so you can round the month down using floorMonth();

```
$this_month = Carbon::parse('2019-07-05')->floorMonth(); // returns 2019-07-01
$start_month = Carbon::parse('2019-06-30')->floorMonth(); // returns 2019-06-01
$diff = $start_month->diffInMonths($this_month);  // returns 1
```

Answer (score 1):

the floorMonth() is completely wrong idea, just think if the date is 2022/09/14 04:01:00 and the next date is 2022/10/14 04/01:00, at this one, the difference is one month, but if we consider the 2022/09/14 04:02:00 and he next date to be 2022/10/14 04/01:00, then the difference of month is not one, it is zero, so the best solution to calculate is:

```
$this_month = Carbon::parse('2019-07-05');

$start_month = Carbon::parse('2019-06-30');

$diff = $start_month->diffInMonths($this_month);
```

Comment: how would you go about rounding up, or does it round up automatically? 
Date 1: `11/01/22` Date 2: `11/30/22`

This is not a full month but i want to still round it as a whole month